# SSAS cube gives composite key error in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssas

We migrated our SQL database and SSAS cube from our old server. When opening the cube in visual studio, our reports still work. When we set up a new report and combine a dimension with a measure, we get the following error.

Query (1, 10) Column [Klantnummer] is part of composite key, but not all columns of the composite key are included in the expression or its dependent expression.

When building this report in SQL management studio, we do not get an error.

What could be the issue?

Thank you for your help!
Esmee

Answer (score 2):

I'm a colleague of Esmee in this project. The problem occurred while selecting this SSAS datasource in SSRS, in Visual Studio. After a while, we discovered that the wrong connection type was selected. In the Query Editor window, we should select MDX instead of the (in our case) standard DAX.

[image: screenshot]

This solved our problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm have the same recommendation to this answer when your SSMS run correctly and
The problem occurred while selecting this SSAS datasource in SSRS, in Visual Studio. After a while, we discovered that the wrong connection type was selected. In the Query Editor window, we should select MDX instead of the (in our case) standard DAX.